# Tampermonkey Script - Create Post in GHOST-blog

Tags: macros, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, ghost-blog

i have a school asignment on which I am supposed to create about thousands of posts on my GHOST CMS. I have tried to automate this process using Tampermonkey scripting but to no avail since my skills are not that great. How would I go about to succeed with my task?

Comment: For one time you it can be a lot easier to just use the browser's JS console. Ctrl+Shift+J on Chrome. You can type entire scripts in and run directly in the page's scope.

Comment: To do what you ask, we would need specific information about the webpage.

Comment: They use a really strange format, and it looks like a stupid embedded scripting language. but for example `$('#ember1085 a')[0].click(); $('.js-publish-button')[0].click();` Published the current page, but when I went to do it again it was renamed. `$('.CodeMirror-code').append('<pre class=""><span style="padding-right: 0.1px;">Your Text HERE</span></pre>');` Seems to add a new line of text to the document. But does not actually save the content.

basically, it is too custom to work without a whole lot of work and expertise.

Comment: But a better way might just be to use a macro. Automate your keyboard and mouse.

Or maybe some utility already exists?

Or, it is possible the easiest way would by to try and capture the packet the page sends, and edit/resend. For example doing this can allow you to send billions of instant messages. But that depends on how the Ghost server is set up. Possibly it is just individually sends keystrokes, instead of the whole thing at once.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers. Appearently when adding the text inside the posts content the CMS saves every single letter in a draft so when adding text via the DOM using scripting, there is an error since there are too many letter added at the same time. And before even adding something, a class called codemirror-focused must be added to the Codemirror element. I think that using a macro in this case is actually the easiest way, however, It seems like the easiest way to succeed is to generate sql code and add posts that way directly in SQL Workbench. Thank you for all your help and tips!